# How correctly and cost effective to store EC2 instance backups

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

How correctly and cost effective to store EC2 instance backups?

I have a scenario like:

- Create EC2-instance snapshot.
- Move it to S3 bucket.
- Move it from S3 bucket to Glacier
- Done

It is correctly solution or I can do it somehow with [Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/storagegateway/)?
PS. All our infrastructure is located in Amazon

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Depending on your change rate I would keep one snapshot for fast recovery. Besides that doing a backup which can de-duplicate over multiple backups might be cost-optimal if you need that kind of history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to 3-2-1 rule and recent ransomware attacks, it is beneficial to go VTL backups. This kind of data is (still) resilient to ransomware. VTL Gateway being implemented in the cloud is cost efficient as well. You pay for AMI running gateway only for uptime.

In case you already have a backup software running tape jobs it would look like:

- Boot VTL Gateway
- Create EC2-instance full backup
- Write backup to VTL tape (rotating tapes according to backup plan)
- Shutdown VTL Gateway until next backup job.

Comment: You can't use an EBS snapshot, as you can't access them directly. What kind of snapshot would you use?

Comment: 1. Snapshots are not backups. Never have been, never will be. These guys thought that EBS snapshots were backups as well theregister.co.uk/2014/06/18/code_spaces_destroyed 

2. Snapshots in AWS are taken at the storage level EBS only. For your setup of EC2 cloud, I would consider backup files.

Answer (score 1):

EBS snapshots of EC2 instances are in a part of S3 you can't access. You can't back up EC2 instances to Glacier via EC2 snapshots.

You can of course copy your data anywhere you like. You might be able to find a way to take an image of the entire instance some way other than EC2 snapshots and store that in Glacier, but I'm not sure how you'd restore it. It's probably possible though.

Comment: And which will be the best cost effective solution to store snapshot., We don't have another solution to do it, only standard snapshots?

Comment: @GVArt there are many possible solutions involving varying levels of complexity and outside-the-box thinking, but there's only one native solution.  EBS snapshots are automatically deduplicated, so if (e.g.) you store two that are almost identical, the second one costs nearly nothing.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a third-party backup software e.g.Cloudberry that can help in your situation? The tool has both free and paid versionings and it can do all the work for you? Have you thought about it?

Comment: Don't do CloudBerry: there are fantom data corruption issues with it.

Comment: Well, thanks for the info, but I haven't had anything up to now. I usually try to go to their tech support and solve any issue.

Comment: You're lucky. Reddit is full of horror stories.

Comment: "Anyone else experience files being corrupted by CloudBerry?"                                 https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/66qeky/cloudberry_backup_beware/

Comment: "Yeah, silent data corruption is another one" https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5qwx9k/big_data_backups_to_the_cloud/

Comment: "We keep receiving an errors "unexpected end of stream" when attempting to restoreone VM." https://www.reddit.com/r/cloudberrylab/comments/66834k/cloudberry_backup_restore_failing_amazon_s3/

Comment: We're happy Veeam stopped working with CBL to have native cloud tier.

Comment: @Mary17 do you work for Cloudberry?

Comment: No, i don't work for them, but I do find their tool cool and great and I did not have any trouble issues with it. But may it is only a question of time before I have any.